# Add a dominoes falling effect after projectile hits a dominoes in Processing?

Tags: processing, collision, projectile

I am trying to make a game in Processing in which the user has to hit a projectile to a series of dominoes, and once the hit happens, all the dominoes after it start falling.

Example: http://www.fallingdominoes.com/

That is, all the dominoes key are initially straight: | | | | | | | | | |

Once, a projectile hits say the first domino, then: / / / / / / / / / / /

Say, the projectile Hits the 6th domino, then: | | | | | / / / / / / /

The code and game for the projectile is here: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/28940

All this happens in processing.

Can someone help us out as to whats exactly to be done? and How its to be done?

Comment: in 2d or 3d ? (btw, the fallingdominoes example is a a pre-rendered scene, always playing back the same sequence at the same time)

Comment: We need way more information than this. Are you talking about a full-blown physics model where the first domino hits the second one, which hits the third one, etc? Or are you just talking about displaying some dominoes standing up and other fallen down? You'll also have more luck if you post an example here (not your whole program, but enough that we can copy and paste to get an idea of what you're going for).

Answer (score 1):

Here, I made a small test for you! Its not a fully implemented physics engine but I guess its close enough...

```
int numberOdominos = 60;
Domino [] myDominos = new Domino[numberOdominos];
int currentDropDomino = -1; 
void setup() {
  size(600, 100);
  myDominos[0] = new Domino(null);
  for (int i = 1; i < myDominos.length; i++) {
    myDominos[i] = new Domino(myDominos[i-1]);
  }
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  String s = getDominoState();
  fill(255,0,0);
  text("press any button from 0 to " + myDominos.length + " to drop that domino and all subsequent ones!!!! (r to reset)",20,10,width,height);
  fill(255);
  text(s, 5, 40, width, 100);
}
String getDominoState() {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = 1; i < myDominos.length; i++) {
    if(currentDropDomino != -1 && i == currentDropDomino) {
      myDominos[i].push();
    }
    result += myDominos[i].state;
  }
  if(currentDropDomino != -1) currentDropDomino += 1;
  if(currentDropDomino > myDominos.length) 
      currentDropDomino = -1;

  return result;
}
class Domino {
  Domino previous;
  char state = '|';
  Domino(Domino previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
  }
  void reset() {
    state = '|';
  }
  char checkPrevious() {
    if (previous.state == '/') push();
    return state;
  }
  void push() {
    state = '/';
  }
}
void reset() {
  for(int i = 0; i < myDominos.length; i++) 
    myDominos[i].reset();
}
void keyPressed() {
  if(key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
    reset();
    return;
  }
  int pushDomino = 0;
  try {
    pushDomino = Integer.parseInt(""+key);
  } 
  catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    println("thats not a number...");
    return;
  }
  if(pushDomino < myDominos.length) currentDropDomino = pushDomino;
}
```

You only have to change the keyPressed() method with one of your choosing; something like `throwProjectileAt(int position) {}`